# Filtering JSON reply in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to filter out the reply I get from a JSON query to the Glosbe.com API.

Currently I've been able to break the JSON down to only receive the meanings but I'm unsure how to remove all of the commas and other aspects of the JSON response. I basically just want to display each meaning on a line of it's own.

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#term').focus(function(){
var full = $("#definition").has("definition").length ? true : false;
if(full === false){
 $('#definition').empty();
 }
});

var getDefinition = function(){

 var word = $('#term').val();

  if(word === ''){

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>We haven't forgotten to validate the form! Please enter a word.</h2>");

  } 

   else {

    $('#definition').html("<h2 class='loading'>Your definition is on its way!</h2>");

    $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=" +word+ "&pretty=true&callback=?", function(json) {

       if (json !== "No definition has been found."){

           var reply = JSON.stringify(json,null,"\t");
           var n = reply.indexOf("meanings");
           var sub = reply.substring(n+8,reply.length);
           var subn = sub.indexOf("]");
           sub = sub.substring(0,subn);

             $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">We found you a definition!</h2>  <h3>'+sub+'</h3>');

          } 

else {
             $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=rus&format=json&phrase=&pretty=true" + "?callback=?", function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                $('#definition').html('<h2 class="loading">Nothing found.</h2><img   id="thedefinition" src=' + json.definition[0].image.url + ' />');
             });
          }
     });

  }

return false;
};

$('#search').click(getDefinition);
$('#term').keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13){
   getDefinition();
}
});

});
```

HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="author" content="Matthew Hughes">
<title>Dictionary Web Application</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="dictionary.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Dictionary Application</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="fetch">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a word..." id="term" />
        <button id="search">Define!</button>
    </section>
    <section id="definition">
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>Created by Matthew & Spencer</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply "parse" the JSON directly? It's JavaScript after all.

Comment: Can you explain this Stephen?

Comment: I think @kielni's answer captures the essence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is JavaScript Object Notation.  You can use it to send JavaScript objects around.  You should take advantage of this, not flatten it and mess with string parsing.

Your `json` variable contains something like this:

```
{
...
"tuc": [
    {
        "authors": [
            1
        ],
        "meaningId": null,
        "meanings": [
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "text": "The process of applying a test as a means of analysis or diagnosis."
            },
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "text": "difficult, tough"
            },
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "text": "Present participle of test."
            },
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "text": "The act of conducting a test; trialing, proving"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
    ]
    }
```

You can access the section with the meanings with `json["tuc"]`; each of those contains an array of meanings (ie `json["tuc"][0]["meanings"]`).  You can loop through each of those and extract the `text` property to build up your output.

For example, inside `.getJSON`, once you've verified that you do have data:

```
    var meanings = "";
    json["tuc"].forEach(function(tuc) {
        tuc["meanings"].forEach(function(m) {
            meanings += "<p>"+m["text"]+"</p>\n";
        });
    });
    $("#definition").html(meanings);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your example. What is the "tuc"?

Comment: It's part of the JSON response that's in your `json` variable.  You can look at it in your JavaScript console and/or on the command line (`curl "http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=engformat=json&phrase=test&pretty=true"`)

Comment: But the variable is different for every word which is searched?

Comment: The keys (`tuc`, `meanings`, `text`, etc) are always the same. The values depend on the search string.

Comment: Hi Kielni, I have been working with the code you gave me above and it is only working when I search for the word "word" and nothing else. Is there something I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, step through it in the debugger and see what you find.  Read the docs on the glosbe.com API to see if there are any cases not covered (is there always a tuc field? are there always a list of meanings?)

Comment: There are not many docs on the Glosbe API, it's quite poorly supported. But we have no choice to use it at the moment. Is it due to the +word+ in the $.getJSON URL?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined